# Condition not working and form submitting even though email already exists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check email avaliablilty using AJAX and PHP, but I am facing the following two problems:

1) If I'm getting response true or false showing me "Email available" message, means if else condition is not working with response.

2) The form still submitting if email already exist.

Here is my code in view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").blur(function(){
      var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Register/check_emails",
        data:{ email:email},
        success:function(response)
        {
            alert($.trim(response));
        if($.trim(response) == "true")
            {
                alert("trueeeee");
                $('#lgmsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Valid Email</span>');
            }
            else 
            {
                alert("falseeee");
                $('#lgmsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Email avaliable</span>');
            }  
        }
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my controller function where I am getting response/result

```
public function check_emails()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $record['data']=$this->Home->check_emailsd($email);
        if($record['data']=="exist")
        {
            echo "true";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "false";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far? What is the response from `$this->Home->check_emailsd($email);` when an email does and doesn't exist? Have you confirmed this method is returning the expected result?

Comment: First of all check if there is any error in console

Comment: Also I would like to mention that if your html form continas button with type='submit', then your form will be submitted even though email exists. You have to provide more detailed information (maybe snippet?) if you are really asking for help.

Comment: Paste your HTML, part of the problem is surely there

Comment: @OliverMGrech: actually in response (alert) i am getting same output in both cases